# Why can't I use server controls in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting ready to be responsible for leading the development of a small ASP.net MVC application.  This is my first time creating an MVC application, so I am excited!

I've carefully read over the documentation and I feel like I have the general idea of how MVC works.  However, if I understand correctly, server controls (like GridView, for instance) are not part of MVC.

My question is: Why?  At my development shop, I'm so used to using controls like GridView and the MS Chart Controls that I'm almost at a complete loss as to developing without them.  It seems almost like starting over.

Why are the server controls unavailable?  How does Microsoft expect me to work without them?  What are the alternatives?

Comment: The whole point of MVC is to not use server controls.

Comment: I thought that the point of MVC was separate development into different concerns to make testing easier and speed development, among other things.

Comment: OK; _one of_ the whole points MVC is to not use server controls.

Comment: +1 one for that comment...sounds a little snarky but was thinking the same thing. More funny then snarky I think, I'm sure it was meant in good humor.

Comment: One of the important things to think about is that every request in your MVC application should not require state to run.

Comment: And if you are really in need of server controls, you can have a hybrid application of ASP.Net Webforms and MVC together but looks like your doing a Greenfield project so no need.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> My question is: Why?

Because most of them depend on things like ViewState and the Postback models which are part of the classic WebForms model and no longer exist in ASP.NET MVC. Those server side controls rely on events that will perform postbacks to the server persisting their state in hidden fields (ViewState). In ASP.NET MVC you no longer work with events such as `Button1_Click`. In ASP.NET MVC you work with a Model, a Controller and View. The Controller is responsible for receiving user requests, querying the Model, translating the results into a view model and passing this view model to the View whose responsibility is to display it under some form.

In ASP.NET MVC there are HTML helpers that could be used to generate some reusable HTML fragments between views. You may take a look for example at the [Telerik ASP.NET MVC suite](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx) of such helpers. They call them controls but they have nothing to do with classic WebForms server side controls. They are just HTML helpers.

Basically classic WebForms are a leaky abstraction of the web. What Microsoft did back in the time when they designed this framework was to bring existing Windows developer skills to the web which was getting more and more momentum. But since the web was still a new technology that most developers weren't yet familiar with, they created this abstraction to hide away the way that the www works. Those developers were accustomed to drag and dropping controls on their Windows Forms, double clicking on buttons that was generating some code for them in which they put their data access logic and so on. This model was transposed to web application development thanks to WebForms. The HTTP protocol was successfully hidden behind this abstraction called WebForms. For example you don't need to know HTML, nor Javascript, not even CSS in order to create a website using WebForms which is really great because the framework abstracts all those things for you. Unfortunately by doing so it prevents you from easily utilizing the full power of lower level web technologies which some people might need when developing web applications.

What ASP.NET MVC does is basically remove this leaky abstraction and bring the www to the developers the way it was intended to be by its creators. ASP.NET MVC is not mature enough compared to classic WebForms so you cannot expect to find the same range of available controls and widgets but things are slowly shifting.

I would recommend you start here with ASP.NET MVC: http://asp.net/mvc. Go ahead, watch the videos, play around with the samples and see if ASP.NET MVC is for you or not. And of course if you encounter some specific difficulty or question don't hesitate to come back here and ask it.

Comment: ++. Whereas WebForms maintain state and have the concept of a postback, MVC migrates back to more of the normal web model where state is not persisted and the concept of a "postback" does not exist. .NET MVC has the concept of "helpers" that in a way can replace the server controls you are used to. Do a search for "WebGrid Helper" and that will give you an idea of how things can be done in a MVC world.

Comment: I agree to the benefits of MVC over the leaky WebForms, however MVC's approach it taking this too far, there are obvious benefits of having XML markup-based components which they encapsulate HTML and save time in development, prevents rewriting a lot of repetitive HTML code and adds a layer of logic (ability to build adaptive/device aware controls).
I think writing C# into Views is not natural programing practice for UI!

Answer (score 10):

> I'm so used to using controls like GridView and the MS Chart Controls that I'm almost at a complete loss as to developing without them. It seems almost like starting over.

In this case, starting over is ***good***.

I've gone through a similar journey. If straight HTML scares you, try working with the `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` namespace. This will allow you access to standard HTML controls, but you'll still have the comfort of turning them into server controls if you need to (either by specifying the `runat="server"` attribute, or by converting them into equivalent ASP.NET controls.

In addition to [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039085/277136), there's another problem with ASP.NET: you're bound to Microsoft's view of the web. That `GridView` you love? It's generating bad HTML. The `Paging` controls it provides? Even worse. Even if you know very little about HTML compliance, nested tables should give you the chills. In a way, everyone who uses a `GridView` is lucky that legacy web supported by Microsoft (and to a lesser degree, Google and Mozilla) came from such a **god awful** starting point.

Finally, to summarize: my suggestion is that you try to rewrite your pages or develop new web applications (as best as you can) using `HtmlControls` only. You'll probably have to learn some JavaScript/jQuery, and might have to venture into the world of AJAX to make your controls operate the way you want them to.

Use this as a stepping stone into the world of MVC. You won't use the same technologies (and may drop a lot of JavaScript/jQuery), but it will help you change the way you think about web development in much smaller, and perhaps easier-to-absorb chunks.

Ultimately, however much you like your ASP.NET controls, you'll have a much greater degree of freedom, **and** you'll also be developing websites that make use of newer technologies, which will provide added value to your websites.

Comment: If you are careful and tell ASP.NET to use xhtml markup in web.config (can't remember the exact setting), the markup really isn't that bad.

Comment: I tried that setting; the `GridView` still outputs nested tables for paging controls.

Comment: I should clarify, it generates mostly valid html. But you are right, it uses tables way too much.

Comment: Straight HTML does not scare me.  I simply think of server controls as being a convenient way to avoid repeating myself.

Answer (score 3):

At the core of this is Model View Controller (MVC) which promotes decoupling. The idea is that you feed your View (web page) a Model with all the data that it needs to be rendered. Server controls are tightly coupled. There is no concept of state in MVC or 'should' be no concept anyways.

Answer (score 3):

That's kind of the point of MVC. It takes away the high level of UI abstraction that server controls provided and leaves you with html and javascript. (It also adds some really cool model binding features)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to MVC and have found using Partial Views to be similar in creating small, reusable UI elements that do not fit into the _Layout. For example, sliders, slideshows, navigation, featured sections although you can use @section for this I find partial views to be more beneficial. This concept enables me to create reusable libraries that I can switch out easily and use in other projects. To me this is similar to controls, although there is a debate both for and against this analogy.