# Using RazorEngine in a ASP.Net server control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, custom-server-controls, razorengine

We have several ASP.Net Webforms sites, and are looking at ways to share controls between the sites. One way mentioned is to use server controls, rather than user controls.

However, my understanding is that the downside of server controls is that the markup is now defined in the `Render` method, rather than in `.ascx` file.

I have been reading about people using RazorEngine for building email templates, and was wondering if the same principle could be applied to server controls, but have not found any info on this.

Is it possible to write re-distributable (i.e. compile to DLL) server controls using `.cshtml` templates via the RazorEngine library? Are there any major reasons to not do this?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039019/why-cant-i-use-server-controls-in-asp-net-mvc, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405955/using-asp-net-server-controls-in-mvc and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32356/Custom-controls-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I am looking for Webforms solutions. The RazorEngine library provides a Razor template parser decoupled from MVC, and I am thinking of using this with custom server controls.

Comment: you can create your custom view engine in asp.net web from too