# Using Web Forms CompositeControl in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, webforms

We are currently migrating an application from **Web Forms** to **ASP MVC**. Due to the size of it it's difficult doing it all in one go, so we are going to try to have an hybrid for a bit.

We are trying to reuse some of our user controls (`.ascx` files) from Web Forms and we have had no problems when they are inheriting from `System.Web.UI.UserControl` because `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl` inherits from it.

However, the problem seems to occur when they inherit from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeControl`. Is there an equivalent of this class in MVC like `Page` -> `ViewPage` and `UserControl` -> `ViewUserControl` that can be used to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, Because those controls inherits from `WebControl` which depends on things like `ViewState` and the Postback which are part of the classic WebForms model and no longer exist in ASP.NET MVC.

Also check the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039085/499930